# Place 3dmodel on gpslog in cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to place a 3dmodel on GPSLOG time series data read from GPX in Cesium.
I didn't see anything specific in the sample code on the official Cesium site, so can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sadly it looks as if Cesium's GPX loader doesn't create the right kind of entity (with a SampledPositionProperty) that one could attach a 3D model to.  I think you might have to run the data through a GPX->CZML converter, and then assign a model to it.

Comment: @emackey　I see.
I will explore on how to convert it to CZML.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by getting the entity and following the 3dmodel.

```
  let activeDataSource;

  let bikeroot =viewer.dataSources.add(Cesium.GpxDataSource.load(`URL`,{
    waypointImage: pinBuilder.fromUrl(
      "bicycle",
      Cesium.Color.BLUE,
      48
  )}
))
  .then(function (dataSource) {
    viewer.flyTo(bikeroot);
    activeDataSource = dataSource;

      const entity = activeDataSource.entities._entities._array[0]; 
      const entity_01 = viewer.entities.add({
        position: entity.position,
        model: {
          uri: "../model/untitled.glb",
          minimumPixelSize: 84,
          maximumScale: 100,
        },
    });
    viewer.trackedEntity = entity_01;
  });
```